# where created files are stored physically in android?

Tags: android, file, directory, storage

I am creating file using following code

```
      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("try.txt",0));
      // write the contents on mySettings to the file
      out.write("erterter");
      // close the file
      out.close();
```

Comment: @Tim I see now, deleted my erroneous comment then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files created in this manner are stored in your application's private storage: `/data/data/com.package/files`

Comment: Please help i can not find such location in my app's folder structure

Comment: @MihirBhatt the directory is hidden unless your device is rooted. If you are rooted download [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en) from the market to find this directory.

Comment: If you are not rooted or using the emulator, you won't be able to access that location except from within your own app. On the emulator, you can use the DDMS FileExplorer tab to access it. If you are rooted, you can use adb shell from your computer or, as @Tim suggested, a root-enabled file explorer on the device. Note: 'com.package' should obviously be replaced with your own package.

Comment: i have checked , i dont find hidden directory.

Comment: If you have already run the code you posted in your question, the files directory will be there. If you have not, there likely won't be a files directory until you do run it. Otherwise, you'll have to explain exactly what you tried and what the result was because I can assure you, that's where files created like that will go.

Comment: @nEx.Software, i had run the code but there were not any directory that is created. i just want to create xml file.